# What did Putin do to ensure that he doesn't get overthrown by a military coup or to reduce the likelihood of it?

Tags: russian-federation, geopolitics, vladimir-putin, dictatorship, coup

What did Putin do to ensure that he doesn't get overthrown by a military coup or to reduce the likelihood of it?

https://www.usnews.com/news/world-report/articles/2022-05-25/new-punishments-await-russian-defectors-as-putin-grows-alarmed-over-ukraine

> Several Kremlin watchers familiar with inner workings in Moscow tell
> U.S. News the introduction of the bill reflects growing concern among
> Russian elites of the rates of defectors on the battlefield in
> Ukraine, along with reports that hundreds are volunteering to join
> specialized units in the Ukrainian army composed of disaffected
> Russian citizens.

There's increased defection and the number of discontent people is growing. I am thinking it should raise alarm and the elites are considering that there's also a risk of a military coup happening.

Now, I am wondering what the Russian elites did to prevent that from happening, and in general what might be the steps usually taken to remedy a similar situation.

Comment: Millions on the paylist of local police and intelligence services spying on the own population and army while also forbidding any show of opposing opinions. Isn't this the time honored solution of every authoritarian system in the world? Do you want to know more specific actions? If so, what specifically are you interested in?

Comment: He must have taken some sort of actions to increase his security, and reduce the likelihood of people betraying him RECENTLY.

Comment: Why must he has done something? Is the normal working of the Russian security apparatus not intimidating enough? In your quote there is only report about a "growing concern". But that doesn't mean that some action must have performed, or does it?

Comment: Typical things you'd do to avoid coups are:  appoint only very trusted and rewarded officers to capital district locations, get the military nice perks and shiny toys, rotate officers frequently from units, make some examples, reinforce your own security staff, use spies and informers, add agents provocateurs to get conspirators to show themselves...  But I am unsure battlefield defections have much in common with palace coups, *at this stage*.

Comment: "There's increased defection and the number of discontent people is growing" sounds like the narrative that Western media peddle non-stop for 4 months now, which should make you question its validity (if discontent would grow monotonously shouldn't it be visible by now?)

Comment: @alamar to be fair, there is also no lack of reporting in Western media that Putin has seen a surge in popularity since the start of the "special military operation".  But, yes, wishful thinking on Putin getting the boot anytime soon.

Comment: Check out [Rules for Rulers - GCP Grey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rStL7niR7gs) & [List of journalists killed in Russia - Under Putin (since 2012)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_journalists_killed_in_Russia#Under_Putin_(since_2012)) & [Media freedom in Russia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_freedom_in_Russia) & [Semion Mogilevich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semion_Mogilevich)

Comment: Honestly the only thing you can infer about *anything* to do with the Russian heirachy from the press is that the American intelligence agency is spectacularly good at what it does (all those assasinated generals, thats gotta involve a very deep leak, and only the US, China and MAYBE Israel [mossad punch well above their weight] has that capacity, and frankly China and Israel are staying well away from that mess. But other than dead generals I wouldnt trust much of what we are being told. The fog of war is thick on this one.

Comment: @alamar Not visible? So all the people getting arrested and jailed, demoted, fired are somehow not visible to you? Or all your reading materials are published by the Kremlin?

Comment: @stackoverblown I would very like to have you quote some numbers on that to support your claims. Yes there surely are some groups in Russia who are "discontent", but how are you going to prove they are growing in size? All we know is that their top brains fled to Georgia and Israel, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Russia is not really big on military coups.

There was a coup of 1917 (February revolution) which has caused horrible failure of the whole Russian state and the fate of all the military (generals) who participated in that coup was quite grim - they were universally fired by the provisional government then got to shoot each other during the civil war.

There was an unsuccessful coup attempt in 1991 (ГКЧП). This one attempted to counter regime change.

There also was a successful coup in which Paul I was killed. I'm not sure how Paul I compares with Putin, but 1801 was quite long ago.

Comment: There was even an other successful coup relative short time befor in which also the father of Paul I Peter was killed.

Comment: "Russia is not really big on military coups." I was about to ask incredulously "So are there countries *that are* big on military coups?" until I realized there are probably several good examples :-) Now I want to ask "Which countries are 'biggest on military coups'?" (Wikipedia's [List of coups and coup attempts by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_coups_and_coup_attempts_by_country) is substantial, but need a "military" filter)

Comment: @uhoh Countries in Latin America a famos for their coups.

Comment: @convert yes in the moments that it took to realize my question was silly I started with Thailand then moved to Africa then kept going west to the Americas.

Comment: @uhoh Shure Thailand is famous for it coups, but there is posibly a definition problem, since all that coups have never afected the ruling monarcy.

Comment: @convert though more recently that situation is getting more complicated [Relations between Thailand’s army and king are becoming one-sided](https://www.economist.com/asia/2019/09/05/relations-between-thailands-army-and-king-are-becoming-one-sided) and [Rise of Thai king's guard erodes Prayuth's sway over army](https://asia.nikkei.com/Politics/Turbulent-Thailand/Rise-of-Thai-king-s-guard-erodes-Prayuth-s-sway-over-army)

Comment: Ousting of Khruschev could be counted as a 'successful' coup.

Comment: Was the coup of 1991 really “an unsuccessful coup attempt”? It *did* end the Gorbachev era and it *did* lead to a chain of events that ended with nowadays having a hardliner from the KGB ruling the country, trying to undo all of Gorbachev’s reforms as well as reestablishing the empire. Couldn’t be closer to the coup of 1991’s goals…

Comment: @uhoh I'd guess chile. They had like a dozen coups in the last century alone

Comment: ГКЧП is another coup than that one @Holger

Comment: @Holger Yes 1991 was the best example of failed coup, it has reached exact the opposite.

Comment: @alamar only if you think, the KGB can’t plan ahead a few years. Isn’t it striking that the KGB never lost powers, only got a new name, and still is working for Putin? Or that none of the eight straw men got a real punishment, but rather, the new government had a generous amnesty for them?

Comment: @convert so Gorbachev stayed in charge, led the country to true democracy and the KGB got disempowered? Or what “opposite” do you mean?

Comment: ГКЧП tried to basically keep Gorbachev in charge. Can't you just, like, google?

Comment: @Holger Yelzin became the power and the USSR was destroied.

Comment: @alamar they tried to keep him in charge by overpowering and detaining him? I see, you have a very special view on things…

Comment: @Zeus Khruschev also came to power by some kind of a coup.

Comment: Okay, I admit I was wrong. They wanted some President of USSR in charge, though @Holger.

Answer (score 38):

The President of the Russian Federation Vladimir Putin protected himself against the possibility of a military coup or a popular uprising by a combination of measures:

- **FSB** (formerly KGB) officers stationed throughout the **military** observe and report on the suspicious activity in the army ranks.
- **Russian National Guard ("Rosgvardiya")** is separate from the **military**. It purpose is thought to be protection of Putin.
- Putin's approval ratings are high and the **percent of dissenters is low** for a popular uprising to be successful.
- **FSB and Rosgvardiya** are active not only in the military, but also throughout the **general population**, effectively suppressing dissent among in the population.
- Russia **historically** had a very **low rate of successful coups**, especially in the periods of strong government and suppression of the freedoms, such as at present.

**REFERENCES:**

> To prevent a military coup, Putin has created a system that inhibits coups and provides him personal protection. First, F.S.B. agents stationed throughout the Russian military observe and report on dissent throughout the ranks. Consequently, Russian military officers are unable to confidently approach others about anti-Putin sentiment or actions, making the planning and formation of a secret coup very difficult and easy for Putin to discover and punish. If discovered, Putin would then most likely make a public example of the dissenters, further dissuading those questioning his rule to speak up. Second, Putin’s Russian National Guard, the Rosgvardiya, is separate from the military and its de facto purpose is believed to be to protect him in the event of a violent uprising. The F.S.B. and the Rosgvardiya work congruently to shield Putin from the threat of a military coup, making one extremely unlikely. As such, many have hoped that the latest round of protests against Putin’s actions would turn into a mass uprising against the autocratic government.
>
> However, despite protests across Russia, a successful mass uprising against the Russian government remains improbable for three primary reasons. First, according to the ‘3.5% rule’ formulated by Professor Erica Chenoweth, 3.5% of Russia’s population would have to participate in a nonviolent uprising for meaningful regime change in Russia to occur. Although tens of thousands of Russians have been protesting, that number is nowhere near the necessary five million that would be needed to create change in Russia. Second, the F.S.B and the Rosgvardiya are also both used by Putin to stamp out public dissent, making popular uprising more difficult and costly. Finally, the third reason why a mass uprising in Russia is unlikely comes from Russian culture and history.
>
> Although the U.S. looks at Russia and sees an autocracy under the guise of democracy, many Russians see their government in a different light. To them, Putin represents strength and stability to many Russians, especially because his rise to power coincided with the end of the chaos of the 1990s. Moreover, Russia and the Soviet Union were historically ruled by authoritarians, making Russian citizens more comfortable with the idea of a strong central ruler, like Putin. Consequently, more Russians support Putin than many Americans might think, indicated by the fact that his high approval rating has even increased following the invasion of Ukraine. However, this increase could be attributed to the fact that many critics of the regime have left the country since the invasion, thereby increasing the proportion of Putin-supporters in the country. Moreover, Russians have a different understanding of democracy than Americans and therefore do not feel as if Putin is an autocratic dictator. Although many Russians say they support democracy, they tend to think that democratic values such as freedom of the press or the separation of church and state are not important, making Putin’s limitations on these freedoms insignificant.

*Why Regime Change in Russia is Unlikely. By Vanessa Smith-Boyle. Jun 08, 2022: https://www.americansecurityproject.org/why-regime-change-in-russia-is-unlikely/*

---

> Sergei Sazonov, a Russian-born political philosopher at Estonia’s Tartu University [...] also believes that a coup is unlikely. The political system remains internally stable, and the economy has so far suffered less than expected, he said.
>
> Russia’s aggression against Ukraine has prompted the population’s consolidation around the Kremlin, and many people blame economic and other problems on the West rather than on Putin, Sazonov said.
>
> He also argued that the political system encourages the appointment of incompetent and loyal people - ones who are unlikely to organize a coup.
>
> “The whole political system has been built in order to prevent a coup,” Sazonov said.
>
> The Russian army, in contrast with Nazi Germany’s Wehrmacht, is incapable of organizing a coup d’etat, he said. Both the Soviet and Russian authorities have avoided appointing independent, ambitious and competent people to the military due to the fear that the army could overthrow the government, Sazonov argued.

*A coup against Putin: Wishful thinking or a real possibility? By Oleg Sukhov. April 5, 2022: https://kyivindependent.com/national/a-coup-against-putin-wishful-thinking-or-a-real-possibility*

Comment: +1 better to post about actual measures taken than try to rope in historical precedents to make this point.

Comment: To add to this, I have friends in Russia who protested in the past 5+ years ago. Because of this they are not allowed to have bank accounts and their pension is cut off, they cannot leave because their passports are revoked. They were never tried or jailed, merely identified at the protest. It's hard for us to understand in the west, but merely speaking out has massive consequences.

Comment: @gbeeduljqa: I wish your friends only the best! They are brave people, and I respect and admire them.

Comment: Yep, I speak to a fair few russian millenials on twitter, and they are all afraid as hell of protest. I've said that hey, just reach out, people will help them with legal costs if they get in trouble (I sure will, I really believe the way out of this stupid war is to support russian peace people. The lesson of vietnam is strong here) but they are all pretty adamant that the sort of trouble protesters get in is beyond the reach of lawyers. Thats a bad situation.

Comment: All that really means is that the level of actual dissent is unknown. It's like saying "the number of people who enjoy ice cream is very low" because any one who is known to like ice cream is punished. Percentage of dissenters against Putin is actually an unknown number because dissenters are suppressed. Which, historically speaking, is a tactic that works great until the day it doesn't.

Comment: @JamieB: The percent of the Russian population who disagree with Putin is unknown, but most sources agree that it is low. The various poll numbers support that, as does my own personal experience on the Russian-speaking social media (apparently, people get to the banned social media by VPN).

Comment: @Shayne you wrote you have "friends in Russia", I thus presume you're not in Russia yourself, and yet you write "people will help them with legal costs if they get in trouble"... I'd be careful with this, since due to sanctions/boycott, it's quite difficult to get money into Russia, and help them to pay for legal costs.

Comment: @Shayne also "The lesson of vietnam is strong here". The Resistance war was won by Vietnamese fighting in Vietnam, let's not overstate the importance of protests in the US. Ultimately you need boots on the ground to win.

Comment: The Kadyrov-controlled Chechen armed forces are also a significant factor, which is effectively a branch of army that is not under the control of the rest of the military, Russian government or other structures of power but personally to Kadyrov and Putin; structured so that they can't really be trusted by any potential Russian coup structures; and at times having significant armed detachments physically located in Moscow close to Putin and/or other centres of power.

Comment: @berdario , absolutely. But it was a combination of both a loss of will to fight by the americans, and the absolutely stunning fight put up by the vietnam. The vietnamese sent the invaders home in body bags, and the protesters made sure those body bags where politically unviable. The americans could have won if they where permitted to go full evil brutality mode. But when they did that, it led to immediate political whiplash at home. And thats my point, if the press and protesters could have freedom to fight for truth, the Ukranian resistance would be made so much more potent.

Answer (score 24):

The question mentions "military coup", but traditionally in Russia (including the Soviet and pre-Soviet times), the **military didn't play a significant political role**, despite its might. Unlike some other countries (e.g. Turkey, Pakistan, much of Latin America), the army has never been a political actor. This is not just because of the 'watchful eye' of FSB/KGB/etc. (mentioned in Timur's answer), but partly due to the fact that the army has never been a career growth refuge for the smart/educated/ambitious/secular/etc. people, given the difficulty of 'normal' political career (as often happened in those other countries).

And at the top level, any commander showing any signs of independence (e.g. [Zhukov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgy_Zhukov)) was (and is) quickly replaced.

So, we should broaden the question a bit to include any coup, and most importantly an inter-elite one.

For the coup to happen (let alone be successful), there is a simple necessary condition: the people (whether elite or populace) must realise that they **stand to gain more than they lose from the regime change**. In a nutshell, **Putin created a situation where this condition is not satisfied**, particularly for the elite.

Practically the entire political elite owe their wealth and position to the current regime (if not Putin personally). They will only lose from a change.  This was reinforced after (and just before) the current war by making the elite 'burn the bridges' and openly declare support, often with escalating vicious rhetoric. There is just no way back.

(There is a somewhat similar situation in North Korea in this regard: the elite (as well as local business, which exists!) actively support the current regime, even if they understand its deficiency. They just realise they stand no chance in case of regime collapse.)

As for the general population, there are several factors. One is, of course, the increasingly repressive environment (the entire internal army, *Rosgvardiya*, was created specifically to quash any internal dissent). But there is also an ever-increasing share of population directly dependent on the federal budget money (from teachers to military production to the swelled bureaucracy) who, again, stand to lose from change (at least in the short term).

A particularly important sub-section of these people are all the forces (police, FSB, all kinds of military: [Siloviki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silovik)). Apart from swelling their numbers, they were made a truly privileged class: relatively decent pay, very early retirement (at the time when the retirement age is increasing for everyone else), certain immunity from abuse... *They* stand to lose the most, and will defend the regime in earnest. This is a typical tactics of similar regimes (cf. Venezuela) and is quite effective.

Finally, there is a true belief amongst ordinary people that coups and revolutions always end in turmoil and grief. Russia is quite a [survivalist country](https://www.worldvaluessurvey.org/photos/Map%202022%20June%202.png) and doesn't favour radical changes in general.

Comment: The "world values" map (survivalist vs self expression axis) is interesting, but... Morocco appears twice in it.

Comment: @berdario, good catch. Matching with the [previous map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inglehart–Welzel_cultural_map_of_the_world#/media/File:Culture_Map_2017_conclusive.png), the bottom-left position seems to be true. The other instance could be Bahrain...

Answer (score 4):

Russia has almost no history of coups, only a few over the course
of hundreds of years. And those happened when the army had
decided that the leader was too weak.

Back in 2014 when Putin rejected supporting the rebels in
Ukraine after a coup in that country and there were people
demanding that he start a war over this (it was the most popular
tag in social networks), yep, this question could have made
sense. But nowadays? Pointless. But this is only about theory.

In reality there exists in Russian society a global consensus
that the coup of 1917 and the exit from the USSR in 1991 both
cost Russia too much: dozens of millions of lives. In the 1990s
Russia lost over 13 million of its former populace who now lived
under the rulership of different countries as a result of the
breakup of the USSR, because without letting those 13 million
go live under a different country’s rulership, even more people
would have actually died throughout the other now-former Soviet
republics. De-facto modern Ukraine is the result of those events
in the 90s — the typical process of breaking up any huge country,
just as has always happened historically. And the many wars that
happened in 90s in the rest of the former Soviet republics are
also the result of that dissolution.

So nowadays any idea of chaos within the country of Russia (a
coup necessarily always means widespread chaos) is perceived by
its citizens as nothing less than a personal assassination
attempt (because it is clear that any coup would result in the
deaths of millions), and all former coups in the country’s
history are condemned. As example popular idea is that if the
February 1917 coup (when the Army and the nationalists overthrew
the tsar) had not taken place, nowadays there could have been
over 500 million Russians. With people having now the idea of
such an experience, it is impossible for them to even imagine
such a scenario as a coup.

As for the article which you mention — when have they ever
predicted reality about Russia? Right, never. Typical military
propaganda. The article describes ordinary things, as for
example in the United States it can be a life sentence or even
execution. So what? As I said, typical propaganda.

Comment: Can you include a reference for "In 1990s Russia lost over 13 million people as result of dissolve"? I found [this reference](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(17)33322-6/fulltext) that mentions between 3-7 excess deaths following the Soviet Union collapse.

Comment: "nowadays it could be over 500 million of Russians." How is that possible when Russia only has a population of 143 million?

Comment: @Philipp, one of the twists is that in that case "Russians" would mean "subjects of the Russian Empire"... And then, in this model, there would be no WWII (at least, not with such consequences for Russia), no Holodomor, etc. But even then it's a highly dubious estimation.

Comment: @Philipp By Russia is meaned not todays Russia, but The Russian Empire, which is much biger. So it´s the former USSR, Finland and part of Poland we are tallking about.

Comment: @Alexei I believe that Andrew didn’t mean that 13 million Russian people **had actually *died*** in the breakup of the USSR, but rather that that many had “moved” to within some new country’s newly-drawn borders, and so they no longer contributed to the population grand totals of Russia itself. It’s like if all of Siberia were to peaceably secede from Russia, then **on paper** Russia would suddenly “lose” almost 40 million people, but nobody would have actually died. They would merely stop paying taxes to the government of Russia and start paying them to their new country’s government.

Comment: @Philipp If history would take a different turn from 1917 onwards, there obviously would be a different number of Russians today.

Answer (score 3):

How about starting a war now and then?

- Military people get their share of recognition, corruption opportunities and career growth
- Less loyal among them can be intentionally sent to riskier missions with weaker support
- In war time, the higher ups' actions are questioned less even if these actions don't relate directly to the war (e.g. getting rid of certain people or organizations)